# Python exe complains about ModuleNotFoundError about inbuilt module json

Tags: python, json, pyinstaller, exe, modulenotfounderror

I have built an exe using pyinstaller.
Before building exe, I made sure my main script of the project works using python command.
I am using Virtual environment. So I made sure it was activated and it has all requirements of the project. (Json is anyways inbuilt)
My exe gets built successfully
but then When I execute exe, I see the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Main.py", line 15, in <module>
  File "C:\TestAutomation\Frontend\src\json_database.py", line 2, in <module>
    import json
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'json'
```

I dont understand on how to proceed

Comment: *"Json is anyways inbuilt"* It is part of the standard library, yes, but it is still a module that PyInstaller needs to package.

Comment: so I have to mention it in pyinstaller when I build the project?

Comment: You shouldn't have to. PyInstaller should be able to figure it out. I was just explaining the gap in your understanding. I suggest making a minimally representative example, and opening a bug with PyInstaller. Make sure you're using the same Python environment everywhere.